# How can i write this kind of for loop in bash shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

here is the code i wrote in c language. But i don't know how to write this code in bash script. please, can anyone help me with this?

```
int d,k[2][2];
    printf("enter the numbers:");
    for(i=0;i<2;i++){for(j=0;j<2;j++){
    scanf("%d",&k[i][j]);} //catch user input into 2D array
    }
```

Comment: You should also accept the solution given if it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this;

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A array
n_rows=$1
n_columns=$2
for ((i=1;i<=n_rows;i++)) do
    for ((j=1;j<=n_columns;j++)) do
    read -p "Enter number [$i, $j] =  : " number
        array[$i,$j]=$number
    done
done

for ((j=1;j<=n_columns;j++)) do
    for ((i=1;i<=n_rows;i++)) do
        printf "%s " ${array[$i,$j]}
    done
    echo
done
```

Ex:

```
user@user-host:/tmp$ ./test.sh 2 2
Enter nuber [1, 1] : 1
Enter nuber [1, 2] : 2
Enter nuber [2, 1] : 3
Enter nuber [2, 2] : 4
        1        3
        2        4
```

Comment: @MohamedNuzhy could you accept ans. if it works,  pls

Comment: Mr. Muzido.. can you help me out with this. i have number of arrays like P[],k[][],t[] and i want to the following c code in bash. how can i write, pls.
p[0]=(k[0][0]*t[0])+(k[0][1]*t[1]);